# help on geometric probability distribution problem?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

a experience has a chance "p" for success. a person repeats experience up until He got first success after second trial. what is the chance that He achieves second success in the 6th trial?

correct answer: $5p^{2}(1-p)^{4}$

---

My approach was to identify that this problem is a geometric distribution since the number of cycles to success is known. So if a person had a success after second experience the Geo(p) would be (1-p)p now we want to know what is the chance of a second success on sixth experience so I thought it would be $(1-p)p+(1-p)^5p$  which is wrong . any hint?

Comment: This sounds like a negative binomial distribution to me, have you learned about those?

Comment: Hint: the first success can occur at 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th or 5th trial.

Comment: It is already given that the first success occurred on the second trial so $(1-p)^1p$ right? on the sixth trial is $(1-p)^5p$ . but I dont know how to combine these two probabilities.

Comment: I'm confused. I don't see where it is given that the 2nd trial is a success. To me, all it says is that we continue until the 2nd success. Am I misinterpreting? The negative binomial gives the correct answer, by the way.

Comment: Let $X$ be number of trials before first success and $Y$ the number of trials between first and second success, isn't what you're looking for $P(X+Y = 6 \vert X \geq 2)$?

Comment: I don't know how to calculate it with that formula Roger. does above approach ends up to the correct answer?

Comment: It does if $X$ and $Y$ are geometric rv that can take the value $0$ (which would make little sense here though). Use Bayes formula to calculate it.